# Root request after restart not granted

Tags: android, root

I have a rooted nexus 5. when my app requests root access, the superuser popup is shown and i am granted 
root access.
Everything works fine, no matter how many times i request root access , it is granted.
But, when i restart my Android and start my app , i request root access , nothing happens.
i don't get root permissions, the superuser popup is not show nor is there a toast that shows i have permissions or not.
Only after i re-install my app, does it grant me superuser access.

Does anyone have an idea what the issue is?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.
it had nothing to do with the su request.
in the past i tried to create the app a system app , so i added the app .apk to /system/app folder.
in that apk there was no request for su.